# Is there a way to import wireshark http traces into java?

Tags: java, networking, selenium, network-programming

Is there a way to import wireshark http traces into java? or do we have an api set for using wireshark in java? I want to capture network traffic headers using java.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might just try using [jnetpcap](http://jnetpcap.com/), which provides you direct api access to the mechanism (pcap) that wireshark uses.